# Lower and Replace in GridView Template Column

Tags: asp.net

How do you lower Eval("ThreadTitle") and replace empty spaces with '-' character in a Template Column in a GridView

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkTitle" runat="server"
 NavigateUrl='<%# "/" + Eval("ThreadID") + "/" +  Lower(Eval("ThreadTitle")) + "#" + Eval("LastPostID") %>' Text='<%# Eval("LastPostTitle") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

The answer is ((string)Eval("ThreadTitle")).ToLower().Replace(" ", "-") 
i just figured it out